# Blackberry Deploy Error

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

When i tried to deploy a .bar in my bb10 device, i get this error:

```
Info: Action: Install
Info: File size: 1482366
Info: Installing ...
Info: Processing 1482366 bytes
actual_dname::
actual_id::
actual_version::
result::failure 500 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 114: ordinal not in range(128)
com.qnx.bbt.deploy.Deploy$DeployException: result::failure 500 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 114: ordinal not in range(128)
```

can somebody help me please!